# eot font type is not working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to works Gothic fonts in IE8. It is not working in ie8. How to get it ?

```
<style>
      @font-face {
      font-family: GothicNormal;
      src: url("../fonts/gothic.eot") format("eot"),url('../fonts/gothic.woff')   format('woff'), url('../fonts/gothic-normal.ttf') format('truetype');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }
   .paragraph{
      font-family: GothicNormal;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this. Also check one more time about the path.

```
 @font-face {    
 font-family: GothicNormal;
 src: url('../fonts/gothic.eot');
 src: url('../fonts/gothic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/gothic.woff') format('woff');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 }
```

Comment: i have added your styles it is working in ie8..thanks